# I need to place a phone number in a fixed position on every page

Tags: wordpress, types, header, position, fixed

Hope someone can help, I'm a rookie with WordPress, recently made the jump from Joomla.

My client has asked me to put a phone number on every page, top right, just under the navigation, ranged with navigation (right). I want it to be a fixed position so when yo scroll it stays in place until the paralex affect takes hold, I didn't know how to do this, so, with a little digging I found a plugin called 'custom header footer content' this has allowed me to put the phone number in using code within the plugin, however, when you resize the width of the page it moves from left to right and does not keep inline with the other page elements (centred 940px container) and I would like it fixed to be inline with the end of the navigation, any ideas?

I'm sure there must be a better/easier way to do this?

Any advice would be appriciated?

My site is http://xecution.co.uk/pure

When you look at the test site, you may see a phone number floating around in the header, I'm playing around with it as we speak.
Regards

Paul

I need to place a phone number in a fixed position on every page

Comment: I see you have found a workaround placing the telephone number as one of the navigation items. Is it a final solution or you still want to place it under the menu?

Comment: Hi Grzegorz, its not a final solution, i'm just trying to get the thing working as the client is starting to get a little impatient. I am looking at two solutions, the first being my question above and also now i have put the number in the navigation which works great, however, can i just make the phone number button bigger in the navigation without altering the rest of the navigation? Any advise would be appriciated.

Comment: You could style the contact item using the title attribute, e.g. `header nav ul.main-menu li a[title="call now"] { font-size:16px; }`

Comment: Hi Grzegorz, thank you, I'm fairly new to wordpress, do you mind putting down some instructions please (idiot style) thank you in advance, your a star.

Comment: Hi, I have dropped the code in to the custome css and works, thank you. However, the whole of the navigation has dropped down and and phone number has dropped down even further. Is there any way we can move up the navigation and also have the phone number baseline alined so it looks neater?

Comment: You can play with the CSS to achieve the best result e.g. adding those properties:  `top: -3px; position: relative;`